# Integrate with y-values and x-values to find expectation? (with python if possible)

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, python

I have approximations of $f(x)$ and value of $x$ as two vectors. i.e

```
f(x) = [0.01, 0.02 ... 0.01]
x = [2000 2050 ... 2500]
```

I want to find expected value of $x$, which is defined as the integration of $x*f(x)$ w.r.t. $x$  i.e.

$E[x] = \int_R x f(x) dx$

I only have values for the $f(x)$, which means that I can't solve the problem analytically. Does anyone know if it is possible to find the integration with only two vectors? It is possible to do with any package in python? I'm thinking that scipy might have something but have not found anything useful yet.

Thanks!

---

EDIT
Both x and f(x) are drawn from samples that are not truly normally distributed. So i can not take the sum of $x$ divided by amount of $x$

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but Riemann sums?

Comment: Riemann sum is for approximating the area under the curve. I want the expected value of x, given the samples i have.

Comment: @Ptru: You could use a Riemann sum (or Simpsons' Rule) for $x f(x)$ instead of for $f(x)$.

Comment: Browsing the scipy documentation it seems like [scipy.integrate.simps](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) is what you need.  This might be a question better suited for [SO:scipy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy).

Comment: Ok, so it should be some kind of riemann sum. Thank you! I didn't know that stackoverflow took mathematics questions. I'll post similar questions on that forum from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just sum up the following:

\begin{equation}
E\lbrace X \rbrace
\simeq
\frac{1}{N}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^N
x[n]
f(x[n])
=
\frac{1}{N} \Big(0.001 \times 2000 + 0.02 \times 2050 + ...\Big)
\end{equation}
This is just rephrasing what @Callus meant

Comment: Yes, as long as the difference in x values are all the same.

Comment: Why do we divide by N? Does this apply to the variance also, that we need to divide by N? The expected value for discrete distribution does not divide by N i.e. mu = sum(x*p(x)). Do you have source of more information to read? Thanks alot btw :)